# Nuxt Generate request failed with status code 500

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I get an error while generating the project I developed with nuxt. There are codes in the related page that I use asyncData and send service requests. When I delete these codes, I do not get errors, but when there are request codes, I get the following error. I wonder why?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf5ic.png)

Comment: It seems that the API you are making the request to is throwing that 500 error. Have you checked it's log?

Comment: when you delete the code actually you remove request to server so error is vanished. 500 totally is a server error and relates to HTTP requests